# Is there any way to change home page on small screen?

Tags: 7

I want to change the home page for small screen. Is there any way to set the front page according to the screen size by using `hook_preprocess_page()` or any other?

Comment: Use **Responsive Layout CSS** for your requirement. References
**[Responsive Theming](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/responsive-theming-how-apply-responsive-design-techniques-drupal-theme)**

Comment: I am using panels module and created a layout. I have to change different layout and can't be possible with media queries.

Comment: If you add the **responsive CSS** then the layout will adjust based on the screen size. No need to use **media queries**, just add the responsive CSS.

Comment: Don't give exact width just use percentage like `height: auto;max-width: 100%;` this will resize based on the screen size.

Comment: I know that, but my structure is something different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Mobile_Detect API and redirect the page using hook_preprocess_page in template.php.

Comment: May you expand your answer to make it more helpful for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question (*Is there any way to set the front page according to the screen size*). No. Especially as you mentioned that you don't want to use JavaScript in a comment to Inizio.

The server by itself has NO idea of the screen size of the client, so the only way to get that info back would be using JavaScript (either implementing `drupal.settings` or some kind of custom AJAX callback). Any module that you use would alos have to utilise JavaScript.

If you want to change the frontpage based on DEVICE, then that's more realistic, with something like [Mobile Detect](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_detect), [Browscap](https://drupal.org/project/browscap), [WURFL](https://drupal.org/project/wurfl) (or something similar) but again - not foolproof.

Comment: I used mobile detect thanx.